# Return true only if there is existing match, but it's not first one

Tags: c#, regex

I think I already wrote what I want to do in title, so now to the point:

1. I have a .txt file with url links and their source code will be parsed by regex expression.
2. Source code of every link is scraped by this:

   ```
   public static string getSourceCode(string url)
   {
       HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
       HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
       string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
       sr.Close();
       resp.Close();
       return sourceCode;
   }
   ```

Each source code contains these text:

```
..code..
..code..
    <p class="content">

                                exampleexampleexample

                                        </p>
..code..
..code..
    <p class="content">

                                example

                                        </p>
..code..
..code..
```

There are more elements of `content` elements.

3. I get `content` content by this:

`Regex k = new Regex(@"<p class=""question-content"">[\r\n\s]*(\S.*)");
var g = k.Matches(sourceCode);`

Now I can easly extract every match:

```
g[1].ToString() <-- first match
g[2].ToString() <-- second match
g[3].ToString() <-- thirdmatch
```

etc.

But what I want to do is to extract these links where: **first match does not contains `XYZ`, but there is `XYZ` in at least other matches.**

*For example:*

First link's source code contains `XYZ` in first and third match <-- wrong

Second link's source code contains `XYZ` only in first match <-- wrong

Third link's source code contains `XYZ` only in third match <-- success!

## Solution

I get Every match colletion from this:

```
MatchCollection b1 = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"<p class=""content"">[\r\n\s]*(\S.*)");
```

What I do next is 
checking if first match does not contain "example" by this:

`if (!b1[0].ToString().Contains("example"))`

And checking the result of this function:

```
bool checkAnother(int amount, MatchCollection m)
{     
    for (int i=1; i<=amount-1; i++)
    {
        if (m[i].ToString().Contains("example"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So that is the code:

```
            MatchCollection b1 = Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"<p class=""content"">[\r\n\s]*(\S.*)");

            if ((!b1[0].ToString().Contains("example")) && (checkAnother(b1.Count, b1)))
            {dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "GOOD";                   
            }
```

Comment: Is using a regex a hard requirement for this, or simply the approach you're currently trying? Also, what currently is the issue? I can see that you don't have anything that really terminates your regex, but otherwise it seems like a simple set of if/else statements.

Comment: I am using regex there, because my programming skills are not good enough (atm) to use better solution to my needs.

Comment: I'd suggest using a DOM walker like [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) (though that one is admittedly no longer maintained), rather than regex for working with XML/HTML-style languages. Still, you're not totally clear on what the _problem_ you're having is.

Comment: Html Agilty pack is another good way to parse HTML http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've heard that HTML Agility pack is very good for parsing HTML. I will try to learn how to use it in my next applications. Thanks for help. I already solved my problem by myself. There is my solution added in first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not suitable for regular expressions.

It's probably *possible* with multiline matching, capture groups and look-arounds, but IMO it's not worthwhile to put lots of effort into an unmaintainable solution.

Try to verify the found matches in a post-processing step instead. Assuming you grab the matches like so:

```
var g = k.Matches(sourceCode);
```

...you can easily achieve that with something like:

```
var isFirstOk = !g[0].Value.Contains("XYZ");
var areAllOk = isFirstOk && g.Cast<Match>().Skip(1).Any(m => m.Value.Contains("XYZ"));
```

Comment: Yes, i know it's not that suitable as HTML agilitypack, or something similar to this. I will try to learn how to use HTML parser. It seems to improve my application's efficient a lot. By now i've solved my problem by myself and put the solution in first post :)